# How to view API usage for specific apps using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a number of web apps (Foo, Bar, Yo) accessing my Google Drive. However, I keep getting errors saying "403 rateLimitExceeded".

Is there a way to know how many API calls (other resources) a single app consumed? E.g. can I get info like this: In the previous 24 hours, Foo app called Google Drive API 100 times, Bar app did it 2500 times and Yo app did it 3300 times?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an API call that fits your use case. However, you can check the quota usage of the project on the Developer Console (and if needed, you can request an increase).

The best practice we can do is to implement batch processing and exponential back-off (as suggested in [Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded)).